# Ansible how to run a role from other role

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible role named "role-a" and "role-b"
When running "role-a" i wish that "rule-b" will be executed as well.

in the main.yml of "role-a' i have added the following

- include_role: role-b

But i'm ending with the following error

> ERROR! 'name' is a required field for include_role.
>
> The error appears to be in
> '/home/ubuntu/mid-project/ansible/roles/role-a/tasks/main.yml': line
> 2, column 3, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact
> syntax problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> ---
>
> - include_role: role-b   ^ here

Comment: Please read the [modules documentations](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#parameters) before your use them and before you ask a question. I don't know how the error could be clearer in this specific case. Moreover, if you really want to make role-a dependent on role-b, consider [adding the dependency in `meta/main.yml`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-role-dependencies) rather than including. This willl ease installing them with ansible-galaxy if you want to do that later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for this would be

```
- include_role:
    name: role-b
```